# How to build .coffee into .js without wrapper function

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm

I'm using 'coffee-script` npm package:

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
var source = coffee.compile('target.js');
```

and I have compiled js inside of `source` variable. But it also wrapped into self-invoked function. I don't need that invocation, b/c I'm using `Webmake` for managing dependencies, that wrap each file.. and I will have 2 invocations.

```
"some.js": function (exports, module, require) {
  (function() {
    var n;
    n = 5;
    alert("hello world " + n);
  }).call(this);
}
```

As you can see, I don't need coffee-script invocation.
P.S. I can't find any documentation about `CoffeeScript.compile` options that is second argument for `.compile`. Can you provide me also that information. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `{ bare: true }` as the second argument to `compile`.

(Wrapping the code twice won't do any harm, though. Is this just for aesthetic reasons?)